# how to return object instead of string with ContentResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

My .NET Core web API project had a sign in POST endpoint and returned the token as a string. Because there was no endpoint url to the generated token resource I didn't return a `CreatedAtAction` and returned this instead

```
return new ContentResult
{
    Content = "myToken",
    ContentType = "text/plain",
    StatusCode = 201
};
```

Now this endpoint returns a class instance holding the access and refresh tokens as properties. Unfortunately the `Content` property only takes strings. Do I have to convert that object to a string? I think the content type is not plain text anymore. How do I return that object correctly with a 201 statuscode? E.g.

```
return new ContentResult
{
    Content = classInstanceHoldingTokens,
    ContentType = "this should be json",
    StatusCode = 201
};
```

When returning `ObjectResult` it only sends back a 200 statuscode.

Comment: Serialize your `classInstanceHoldingTokens` into JSON, so your esentially sending a JSON string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply change the return type to `ActionResult` and return the response like this. You can create a class according to your requirement.

```
object results = ...;
return StatusCode(201, results);
```

Comment: ah yeah, `return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created, authenticationTokens);` did the trick :)